# Unable to deploy Django App to google cloud app engine with MySQL database instance

Tags: python-3.x, django, google-cloud-platform

The response I get is

```
(base) bukenya@bukenya-HP-EliteBook-8460p:~/Downloads/DjangoApplications/ecommerce$ ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances="jumanji-280508:us-central1:ecommerce-instance1"=tcp:3306
2020/06/24 18:35:50 failed to setup file descriptor limits: failed to set rlimit {&{8500 4096}} for max file descriptors: invalid argument
2020/06/24 18:35:53 listen tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: bind: address already in use
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already got a MySQL instance running on that machine looks like.

Try running the proxy like this:

`./cloud_sql_proxy -instances="jumanji-280508:us-central1:ecommerce-instance1"=tcp:3308`

And then have your application connecting on port 3308 instead of 3306 (outgoing it still connects with the same port, that `tcp=3308` is just telling the proxy which port to listen on).